# Filter data in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can I find the users.key value that has myPhone with value = 123

[image]

what I have tried:

```
let usersRef = admin.database().ref("users");
usersRef
            .orderByChild("myPhone")
            .equalTo("123")
            .on('value', function(snapshot) {
                console.log("Snapshot "+ snapshot.val() );

        });
```

Comment: It looks like you're storing the phone number as a number. If so, see my answer below. If that's not the problem, please replace the screenshot with the actual JSON as text. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: See my answer if you want another alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're filtering on a string, but are storing a number. To make it work:

```
let usersRef = admin.database().ref("users");
usersRef.orderByChild("myPhone")
        .equalTo(123)
        .on('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) {
                console.log("User "+userSnapshot.key+": "+ userSnapshot.val() );
            });
    });
```

Although I'd probably recommend actually storing the phone number as a string.

Comment: it works, the problem was with myPhone stored as number. i also tried the snapshot.forEach but the value wasn't there to get the key out of userSnapshot

Comment: You need to do both (as in my answer): use the correct data type **and** loop over the results (since there can be more than one matching node).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is storing the phone number as a string like Frank mentioned like this

```
{
  "users": {
    "yourUID": {
      "myPhone": "123"
    }
  }
}
```

Noticed that i used `"123"` instead of `123`. If you use this method you won't have to use `.equalTo("123")` and use `.equalTo(123)` instead.

When you save the data inside the firebase database use string instead if you want to use this method.