# How do I Query Firebase Firestore for a field of type Geopoint in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying a firestore collection for documents inside of a latitude and longitude range.  Since it appears you can't conduct a query with arguments given to two different fields ('lat', 'lon'), I have assigned a type Geopoint to a single field 'coords' that has the longitude and latitude.  How do I use .where() with geopoints? Below is the general query I would like to use, where _latMin, _latMax, etc. are variables linked to the bounding box of my map.

```
_getDocs() async {
  print('getdocs');
  final QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('collectionName')
      .where(
        'coords',
        isGreaterThan: _latMin,
        isLessThan: _latMax,
      )
      .where(
        'coords',
        isGreaterThan: _lonMin,
        isLessThan: _lonMax,
      )
      .get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    print(doc.data());
  });
}
```

How Do I reference the latitude and longitude inside of coords?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Firestore query can only contain range conditions (`>`, `>=`, etc) on one value. So you *can* filter on *either* the latitude or longitude of the `coords`, but not on both in a single query.

If you want to perform geoqueries on Firestore at the moment, the common approach is to store an additional so-called [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) value in your document, which is a (rather magical) string value that combines latitude and longitude in a way that allows you to query them to filter on geographic blocks.

[image]

If you want to learn how this works, I recommend checking out this video on the topic: [Querying Firebase and Firestore based on geographic location or distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).

If you want to implement this approach on top of Firestore, check out the documentation on [implementing geoqueries on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

I also recommend checking out these previous questions on the topic:

- [How to run a geo "nearby" query with firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630507/how-to-run-a-geo-nearby-query-with-firestore)
- [How to filter Firestore collection data using function (for location distance filtering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607847/how-to-filter-firestore-collection-data-using-function-for-location-distance-fi/53608024#53608024)
- [Is there a way to use GeoFire with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553682/is-there-a-way-to-use-geofire-with-firestore)
- [Firestore multiple range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query)

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful.  And really nice job on your presentation as well!  Much appreciated.